# bcrypt not installing with npm (Mac OS X 10.9 - Node v0.10.22)

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, npm, bcrypt

System specs:
Mac OS X 10.9
Node v0.10.22

I get the following error when trying to install bcrypt. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> bcrypt@0.7.6 install /Users/eDawg/Desktop/eggstage/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
../src/blowfish.cc:47:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/eDawg/Desktop/eggstage/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.22
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.11.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/eDawg/Desktop/eggstage
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/eDawg/Desktop/eggstage/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I was having the same issue for the last few weeks. I was able to successfully download bcrypt 0.7.7 from npm install with node v0.10.22.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to try [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) which is written in native javascript. Apparently there shouldn't be any build issues.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is rather late. But for anyone else having this issue, you need to ensure you are using the correct version of bcrypt. Please see the table below  (which can also be found on their [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)). Node version on the left and bcrypt release version on the right.

```
0.4.x   <= 0.4.x
0.6.x   >= 0.5.x
0.8.x   >= 0.5.x
0.10.x  >= 0.5.x
0.11.x  >= 0.8.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating XCode on my Mac Mavericks 1.9 resolved this for me.